# Pi brown screen before desktop

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Using a pi 4 to make a few samples to show customers and I have managed to add my own splash screen on startup but I get a brown screen before the desktop.  I'm using Pi4 with bullseye, pretty much standard.

1. Splash screen shows for 5 seconds (used initramfs-splash, although issue was there before this)
2. Black screen for 13 seconds
3. Brown screen for 1 or 2 seconds
4. Desktop.

My aim is to clean this up best I can but the brown screen is driving me mad.  I've heard that it is something to do with gnome...
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323987
...but there appears no solution to rid of this inconsistent step.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Raspberry Pi 400 with default Raspberry Pi 32 bit system. Initially there was no brown screen. However, after I use /etc/rc.local to run personal script on startup, there appears brown screen.

My script was not running as expected(make Bluetooth discoverable) and I have not found the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).